# Regular Expression Search in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm not sure if this is possible within VS, but I'm working with a massive VB.NET file that needs to log every function call for debug purposes. Problem is, that not every function has the Log command in it. I'm trying to use RegEx to find the function definitions that do not have a log within them.

This would NOT be a match:

```
Public Function Test1() as Boolean
    Log.Tracelog("Test1()")
    Return True
End Function
```

This WOULD be a match:

```
Public Function Test2() as Boolean
    Return False
End Function
```

The closest I've come is using the following:

```
(function|sub|property) .*\n.*~(Log\.t)
```

In my own mind, it should work, but no matter how I word it, it's still pulling every function as a match, even those that have the "Log.Tracelog" call in the function.

Is there anyway I can search to find the latter case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(function|sub|property) .*\n~(.*Log\.t)
```

I moved `.*` from just before the `~()` (preventmatch) to just inside it.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for! Why does moving the tilde change the match? I've only just learned that I can use expressions to find negatives recently, so I'm not sure of all the ins and outs of them.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the debug.WriteLine methods for the functions you want logged.  You can also use the stack to get the method name:

```
    Private Function test1() As Boolean
    Debug.WriteLine(New System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().GetFrame(0).GetMethod.Name)
    Return False
End Function
```

Then the messages only output when debugging and only in the methods you want.

Comment: That is a handy bit of code to use! I'm pretty new to developing in Visual Studio, so I didn't know I could use function calls to get the method names. This will make things a lot easier. Thank you!